# How can I resolve the forwarded API from the IAT on PE?

Tags: python, portable-executable, import-table

Hi I'm trying to make a Import table builder in python script just like MacT's Import Reconstructor.

But I have a trouble to find out the method to get an original API information from the forwarded API.

For instance, I got a "ntdll!RtlDecodePointer" from IAT but It's forwarded from the "kernel32!DecodePointer" and I have no ideas to find it out.

Should I have to search through every single loaded modules' ForwarderChain in Import directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, `ForwarderChain in Import directory` unrelated to this.

when loader resolve `kernel32.DecodePointer` from some *PE* import - it view that it point to some address **inside** `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` of *kernel32.dll* - this is so called forwarded export. loader in this case understand that `kernel32.DecodePointer` point not to code, but to **string** in form *`somedll.somefunction`* or in form *`somedll.#someordinal`* as result loader is try load *`somedll`* and search for *`somefunction`* by name or for *`someordinal`* by ordinal. this search how you can view can (and in case forward exports was) recursive. it stopped when we finally got function address **not inside**  `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` - this address and will be stored in *IAT* or process fail - we not found dll/or export in this dll.

note that deliminator here (between *dll* and *function* name - not `!` but `.`) interesting question - what be if  *`somedll`* containing `.` in own name - say `my.x64.dll`. old version of windows incorrect process names like this (*`my.x64.dll.somefunc`*) because it search **first** `.` in string by `strchr` - so will be search *`x64.dll.somefunc`* in *`my`* dll and fail. but now this is fixed - loader use `strrchr` - he search for last `.` in string.

as result yearly we can not specify full dll name with extension -

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:fn=kernel32.dll.DecodePointer");
GetProcAddress((HMODULE)&__ImageBase, "fn");
```

fail say on xp. but now - win10 exactly, may be win8.1 (need check) this is correct and will be work - xp will be search for `dll.DecodePointer` in `kernel32` while win10 search for `DecodePointer` in `kernel32.dll`. also from here pointed that early we can not forward export to module without `.dll` extension, now - no such limitation. (loader by default append *`.DLL`* suffix to to loaded library name, if it not containing `.` - so when call `LoadLibrary("my")` - actually will be opened and loaded `"my.DLL"`, but for `"my."` or `"my.x64"` suffix `.DLL` will be not appended (`.` char in name))

so if return to your concrete example - `kernel32.DecodePointer` point to something inside `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` of *kernel32.dll* . loader read **string** by this address - `NTDLL.RtlDecodePointer` - call `strrchr` (or `strchr` old versions) on this string for find `.` and finally load `NTDLL` -> `NTDLL.DLL` (suffix added because no `.` in name) and search for `RtlDecodePointer` - address found and it not inside `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` of *ntdll.dll* - so this is code address. here process stopped and address of `RtlDecodePointer` stored in initial *PE* *IAT* .

you from own side need repeat loader steps. but here exist one problem in modern os - many strings is begin with `API-MS-*` dlls names. this is not real dll but [The API Set Schema](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm) - undocumented and mutable way, how loader resolve this names

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I think I need to study more about the principle of operation... :'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the ability to distinguish a Fowarder string from a regular function address while parsing a module's the export table.

I would not recommend trying to parse this Forwarder string before you know its a Forwarder string as there is a much simpler method.  The trick is to check if the exported function's address falls within the export section memory range.  This is the official method as stated in the PE/COFF specification's "Export Address Table" section.

Sorry, my example code below is in C, not Python, but should still give you the idea.  Also note that the check below works on PE32 and PE64 images.

When you are parsing the export table, you will already have a pointer to the IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY export's section.  From there you obtain a pointer to the IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY. E.g.

```
IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY* pExportEntry = pOptHeader->DataDirectory->arDataDirectory + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT;
...
//code to convert pExportEntry->VirtualAddress into file offset and store in dwExportTableFileOffset
...
IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY* pExportTable = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)(ImageFileBase + dwExportTableFileOffset);
```

Assuming that you have retrieved the function's array pointer from pExportTable->AddressOfFunctions, the following check below works regardless of whether the function is exported by name or oridinal.  If the function address of function #i (shown by arFuncs[i] below) is within the export section (that you are already parsing), the address points to a Forwarder string which has the format <MODULE>.<ExportName>, otherwise its a regular function.

```
if (arFuncs[i] >= pExportEntry->VirtualAddress && arFuncs[i] < pExportEntry->VirtualAddress+pExportEntry->Size)
{
    //function address is RVA to Forwarder String; e.g. NTDLL.RtlDecodePointer
}
else
{
    //function address is RVA to actual code within current module
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your example is so helpful to me!